# Make an image have a static position relative to its parent container?

Tags: html, css, image, static, scroll

I'm making an image preview container, found at **bottom of the page** at this URL:

http://cowperthwaite.dev.mybusinessadmin.com/location/51447

At the bottom, you can see that the thumbnail images get a scroll bar because there's more than can fit in the height of the parent container. That's fine and is working as intended.

The problem I'm having is that I need the LARGE image on the left to *always stay in view*, even when scrolled down. In other words, I need it to stay static in relation to its parent div - always within the yellow box - whereas the thumbnails have a scroll area.

I've tried all manner of `position:_______` variations to no avail, and I feel like I'm missing some higher concept here. I'm also not sure if what I'm trying to accomplish is even possible.

Would someone mind providing some insight? Thanks in advance

EDIT: derp, didn't provide my code...

HTML:

```
<div class="pictureBoxContainer">
    <div class="pictureBox">
        <div class="pBoxLeftColumn">
            <?php
                echo "<div class='pBoxLargeImageContainer'>";
                echo "<img src='$pictureLinks[0]' id='largeImage' alt='Primary Image' class='pBoxLargeImage'>";
                echo "</div>";
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="pBoxRightColumn">
            <?php
            foreach ($pictureLinks as $picture) 
            {
                echo "<div class='pBoxSmallImageContainer'>";
                echo "<img src='$picture' alt='Thumbnail' class='pBoxSmallImage'>";
                echo "</div>";
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.pictureBoxContainer {
    padding: 12px;
    clear:left;
    clear:right;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F7D961;
    border-radius: 12px;
    max-height: 350px;
}

.pictureBox {
    background-color: #FFF;
    border-radius: 12px;
    width: 97%;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 12px;
    max-height: 300px;
}

.pBoxLeftColumn {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 49.99%;
    max-width: 49.99%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.pBoxRightColumn {
    display: block;
    float: right;
    min-width: 49.99%;
    max-width: 49.99%;
    overflow: auto;
}

.pBoxSmallImageContainer {
    height: 103px;
    width: 145px;
    float: left;
    padding: 3px;
    margin: 3px;
    background-color: #F7D961;
    border-radius: 2px;
    position: relative;
}

.pBoxSmallImage {
    max-height: 95px;
    max-width: 138px;
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

.pBoxLargeImageContainer {
    width: 100%;

}

.pBoxLargeImage {
    border-radius: 6px;
    min-width: 450px;
    max-height: 300px;
    position: static;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `position: relative` to `pictureBoxContainer` div and following styling to `pBoxLeftColumn` div:

```
.pBoxLeftColumn {
    display: block;
    left: 25px;
    max-width: 49.99%;
    min-width: 49.99%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the large `img` in a `div` and the thumbnails in a separate `div`, then add `overflow-y:auto;` and give the thumbnails `div` a `height`.

[See demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/xyRcE/1/).

Note: with `overflow-y:auto;`, if your remove some of the thumbs so they don't exceed the height, the scroll bar will go away.

Answer (score 0):

```
.pBoxLeftColumn {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    min-width: 49.99%;
    max-width: 49.99%;
    overflow: auto;
    position:absolute;
    margin-top:0px;
}
```

I guess that this is what you want?